# How to return a pointer to a list of pointer from a DLL?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, dll

I'm working (actually, continuing the work of another) on a DLL that handle bluetooth connection of specific devices.

In the DLL, the devices are "stored" in different channels so I end up with a pointer to a list of pointers to a list of pointers to said devices:
`std::list<std::list<device*>*>* DevicesList`

I've got a `getDevices()` function that return the "primary" pointer that allows me to go through all the devices and acces them (name, BT socket, etc...)

While i'm having no issues going through the lists inside the DLL, once I return the pointer in my main app, i get an empty list and get an `Access violation reading location` error when trying to access the devices attributes.

From my understanding, once the pointer is return from the DLL into my main App, it lost its content (or rather the address of it).

Can someone provide any insight on why this happen and how I could fix this?

This function symply return the pointer to the main app, I edited it for debuging purpose:

```cpp
std::list<std::list<device*>*>* GetDevices()
{
  std::list<std::list<Device*>*>::iterator it;
  std::list<Device*>::iterator it2;
  for (it = BluetoothManager::getInstance()->devices->begin(); it != BluetoothManager::getInstance()->devices->end(); it++)  // devices is std::list<std::list<Device*>*>* 
  {
    for (it2 = (*it)->begin(); it2 != (*it)->end(); it2++)
    {
      if ((*it2) != nullptr)
      {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Name of the device : %s"), (*it2)->name); // Works as intended
      }
    }
  }
  return BluetoothManager::getInstance()->devices;
}
```

Then, in my Main app :

```cpp
std::list<std::list<Device*>*>* DevicesList;
std::list<std::list<Device*>*>::iterator it;
std::list<Device*>::iterator it2;
DevicesList = GetDevices(); // Function from the DLL
for (it = DevicesList->begin(); it != DevicesList->end(); it++) // CRASHES HERE
{
  for (it2 = (*it)->begin(); it2 != (*it)->end(); it2++)
  {
    if ((*it2) != nullptr)
    {  
      _tprintf(TEXT("Name of the device : %s"), (*it2)->name);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `std::list` is virtually never the appropriate data structure. Use `std::vector`. It’s *always* faster, even if you frequently insert and delete data in the middle of the sequence, because of constraints imposed by modern hardware. This is doubly true for small sequences, which is probably what your use-case handles.

Comment: You've got a few problems: (1) There's no guarantee that `std::list` in the app is compatible with `std::list` in the DLL.  One Definition Rule violations are very common when crossing DLL boundaries.  (2) The variable you looped through in the DLL is not the same variable you returned.  Fetch the pointer only once, before the diagnostic prints, and then return the same pointer you just used.   (3) You didn't show us how the pointer is obtained, so it's possible that a temporary variable goes out of scope and you return a dangling pointer.

Comment: Unless you can guarantee that you used the same compiler, compiler version, and compiler options to build your application and DLL, and in addition use the DLL version of the C++ runtime library, passing `std::list` across DLL boundaries will put a halt to everything you're doing now.

Comment: @BenVoigt as i mentioned in the code bloc, the pointer comes from a singleton and I simplified the writing so it was more readable. `BluetoothManager::getInstance()->devices` is also used in the loop... it really is the same I test and returns

Comment: Alright, i'll try with vectors, see if it's better, thanks ! @KonradRudolph

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i'm not actually passing the list but rather a pointer to it, in my app I define another std::list<std::list<device*>*>* DevicesList to wich i pass the pointer returned from the dll